# WPF: How To Customize Generic Custom Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is a tough question, but I'll try to explain anyway...

I have a **custom control** window that is used all over my applicaton. The reason I did this is because I wanted the various windows and dialog boxes to be fully customizable across my program. I.e., the minimize, maximize, close button and frame are all custom. This window is templated inside my generic.xaml. Now this works and it's all good. The idea I got was from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomFrames.aspx

Now the users of this custom window are **user controls** in their xaml they basically use MyWindow as their root element:

```
<MyWindow>
         .... 
</MyWindow>
```

But now what I'm trying to do is "inject" certain elements into MyWindow from the User Control's xaml. MyWindow would simply have a container for hosting them. For example, they might want to inject a toolbar button that appears right next to the minimize button. So for example, I might have a user control that does the following (where MyWindow is the root element):

```
<MyWindow>

<MyWindow.ToolBar>
    <Button x:Name="BlaBla"/>
</MyWindow.ToolBar>

</MyWindow>
```

This would put "blabla" right next to the minimize button for example. But I'm wondering if it's even possible to do this. I.e., the whole MyWindow.ToolBar thing. Is there a construct for this, is this an attached property or something weirder?

Comment: Could you add some details on how your custom window is implemented? Is it your custom class derived from Window? How do you customize Close/Minimize/Maximize buttons on this custom window?

Comment: The question is not clear. Infact I think there are multiple questions. 1. You want to inject certain elements into the 'non-client area equivalent'(it would be similar to how a tab control is done with header and content properties) and 2. inject by whoever USES MyWindow. Try and break down your question. Point 2 doesnt make any sense.

Comment: see my updates I rewrote it to be very clear. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is possible, depends on your choice of types for the `DependencyProperty`. You could use `IEnumerable` and bind the `MyWindow.ToolBar` dp to the `ItemsSource` on your internal `ToolBar`.

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <!-- ... snipped down to the ToolBar ... -->
    <ToolBarTray>
       <ToolBar x:Name="PART_ToolBar" />
    </ToolBarTray>
</ControlTemplate>
```

With the appropriate code in `OnApplyTemplate` to pull `PART_ToolBar` and create new `Binding` for the `ItemsSource`.

**EDIT:** rereading your question it appears that I missed that you wanted to add this elsewhere. My suggestion then would be to use this as an `object` dependency property, with a `ContentPresenter` bound to the `MyWindow.ToolBar` with a `Visibility` set if the binding is not `{x:Null}`.

Comment: There is already a ContentPresenter inside my MyWindow custom control. Can you have multiple content presenters??

Comment: You can bind the `Content` property on the `ContentPresenter`.